# Cython: Method Overloading and Type Conversion

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

**Backgroud**

I'm trying to write Cython codes that work on ndarray and function like pandas groupby. Given two 1D or 2D ndarray "factor" and "group", I want the summary description of the "factor" array, such as mean and std along each row(if 2D) and each group, or operate on the "factor" array, such as de-mean or standardize.

```
>>> factor
array([[3, 8, 6],
       [6, 1, 3],
       [3, 7, 6],
       [1, 3, 4]])
>>> group
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
>>> c_group.group_mean(factor, group)
array([[3, 7],
       [2, 6],
       [4, 7],
       [2, 0]])
>>> c_group.group_demean(factor, group)
array([[ 0,  1, -1],
       [ 0, -1,  1],
       [-1,  0,  2],
       [-1,  1,  2]])
>>> c_group.group_demean(factor[0], group[0])
array([ 0,  1, -1])
```

**Problems**

Except for the implementation of the algorithm, there are still two problems, deal with multi data types and shapes of inputs. Here I follow [cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html), use **fused type** as template for multi data types and write two kind of func for multi data shapes. (Please ignore that mean of integers could be float number.)

```
# import ...
ctypedef factor_type:
    int
    long long
    double

def myfunc(factor, group):
    if np.ndim(factor) == 1 and np.ndim(group) == 1:
        return myfunc_1d(factor, group)
    if np.ndim(factor) == 2 and np.ndim(group) == 2:
        return myfunc_1d(factor, group)

def myfunc_1d(factor_type[:] factor, int[:] group):
    ... 

    if factor_type is int:
        dtype = np.intc
    elif factor_type is double:
        dtype = np.double
    elif factor_type is cython.longlong:
        dtype = np.longlong

    result = np.array(size, dtype=dtype)
    factor_type[:] result_view = result

    ...


def myfunc_2d(factor_type[:, :] factor, int[:, :] group):
    ... 

    if factor_type is int:
        dtype = np.intc
    elif factor_type is double:
        dtype = np.double
    elif factor_type is cython.longlong:
        dtype = np.longlong

    result = np.array(size, dtype=dtype)
    factor_type[:, ::1] result_view = result

    ...
```

**Questions**

1. How can I overload myfunc to deal with both 1D and 2D input instead of implementing both and get a wrapper for them? I tried "myfunc" for 1d and 2d with the same function name and diff input shape, but cython can only compile the last one successfully.
2. Can I write a function for type conversion that can be used for all other functions, such as

```
def type_conversion(type_):
    if type_ is int:
        return np.intc
    elif type_ is double:
        return np.double
    elif type_ is cython.longlong:
        return np.longlong
```

Thanks a lot